# How to update a record from another record in same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a `pricing` table and a `products` table built in MySQL 5.1.70.

New pricing table structure:

```
`priceid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`itemid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
`class` enum('standard','wholesale') NOT NULL
`price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
`owner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Old pricing table structure:

```
`priceid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`itemid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
`price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
`owner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

New products table structure:

```
`itemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
`msrp` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
```

Old products table structure:

```
`itemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
`wholesale_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
`msrp` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
```

Here is an example row from the new products table:

```
'12345', 'Toy Drum', '25.00'
```

Here are two example rows from the new pricing table for the same item:

```
'123', '12345', 'wholesale', '10.00', '2'
'124', '12345', 'standard', '20.00', '2'
```

I have the following query I'm trying to rework to make work with the new table setup above, because the old setup had `wholesale_price` in the `products` table:

```
UPDATE products, pricing, price_rules
SET pricing.price = IF(
    price_rules.markdown > 0,
    products.msrp - price_rules.markdown * products.msrp,
    products.wholesale_price + price_rules.markup * products.wholesale_price
) WHERE
    products.itemid = pricing.itemid AND
    pricing.owner = price_rules.owner;
```

The complication is that both the wholesale price and the standard price are now in the same table under the same `itemid` but different `class`.

How would I make this query work (efficiently) under the new table structures?

Table has about 200,000 records.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Why does your query not work? And for god's sake, next time you ask a question just post the table structure instead of this "this table has this and that table has that" text.

Comment: @fancyPants I've edited the post to be more readable. Query won't work because wholesale price was moved to same table as standard price.

Comment: What's this `price_rules.markdown`? It's missing in your new tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a query that really works - you will worry about efficiency later.

Look at [this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aa45/1), this example shows how to pair together two rows from the same table with 'wholesale' and 'standard' values.

Here is [another demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c918c/1) with an example how the update query might look like (the query is at the bottom of build schema tab), and below are shown results after running this update on sample data.

```
UPDATE products, pricing new, pricing old, price_rules
SET new.price = IF(
    price_rules.markdown > 0,
    products.msrp - price_rules.markdown * products.msrp,
    products.wholesale_price + price_rules.markup * products.wholesale_price
) WHERE
    old.class = 'wholesale' AND
    new.class = 'standard' AND 
    old.itemid = new.itemid AND
    products.itemid = new.itemid AND
    new.owner = price_rules.owner;
```